# Google Spreadsheets RE2 - how to extract alpha-numeric characters only

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract only alpha-numeric characters from a Google Spreadsheets cell with:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

Results:

[image]

What would be the correct expression?

Comment: I couldn't see straight away why regexextract doesn't work. The documentation says 'The first part of text that matches this expression will be returned' =REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[a-zA-Z0-9]+") will work for !abc but not ab¶c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `REGEXREPLACE()` instead:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"[^a-zA-Z\d]+",""),)
```

Or:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"[\W_]+",""),)
```